# jsTree version 3+ - create new node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

how, can i create new node with display input element to edit the title?

I use contextmenu plugin like this:

```
{
  icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-create',
  label: 'Create',
  action: function () {
      tree.create_node(node, 'Title of node', 'inside');
  }
}
```

In version 1, it was automatic...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ajhLqLos/

```
function demo_create() {
    var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    sel = sel[0];
    sel = ref.create_node(sel, {"type":"file"});
    if(sel) {
        ref.edit(sel);
    }
};
function demo_rename() {
    var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    sel = sel[0];
    ref.edit(sel);
};
function demo_delete() {
    var ref = $('#jstree1').jstree(true),
        sel = ref.get_selected();
    if(!sel.length) { return false; }
    ref.delete_node(sel);
};
$('#jstree1')
    .jstree({
        "core" : {
            "check_callback" : true
        },
        "plugins" : [ "contextmenu" ]
    });
```

http://www.jstree.com/demo/